# manually redirecting X output through ssh

Tags: ssh, xorg, authentication, xauth

I have a remote server, on which I am able to log in with ssh.
However there is no home directory for my user.

When I try to `ssh -X` to that server, ssh tries to put a cookie into `~/.Xauthority` which obviously fails and therefore no X output is possible.

As far as I see, there is no way to specify a different file to save the cookie to.

Therefore I tried to set things up manually on a temporary home:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/myhome
cd /tmp/myhome
export HOME=$PWD
xauth add $DISPLAY . $COOKIE
xlogo # test setup
```

In theory ssh should set up the tunnel and set the $DISPLAY properly and the only thing missing is the correct value for $COOKIE.

The value shown with `xauth list` (something like `ffb3c8b945442b70146f7158861f1a54`) on another server seems not valid on this one.

Question:

- Why does a cookie working on one server not work on another one?
- How do I get a working cookie in my case?
- Is there an easier way to set up xforwarding in that case? (besides getting a proper home directory or using an unencrypted `xhost` connection)

Comment: For the first question authentication spoofing seems to be the reason: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch09_03.htm#ch09-28-fm2xml

Comment: I hoped to get access to the cookie by setting `XAuthLocation` but setting this on the client will not set it for the server.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH provides an alternate way to set the X cookie on the protocol side: a [`sshrc` file](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html#SSHRC). This file can be `~/.ssh/rc` or `/etc/ssh/sshrc` (or `/etc/sshrc` or some other location depending on the server configuration). The manual gives a snippet of code to use in that file to set the cookie manually. Unless your server's `/bin/sh` is a pre-POSIX antique, you can simplify this code to

```
if read proto cookie && [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
  echo "add unix:${DISPLAY#localhost:} $proto $cookie" | xauth -q -
fi
```

The manual suggests putting this code after some code that sets up the home directory — in your case you'd set the `HOME` environment variable, possibly create a temporary directory for it first.

Your code is similar but keeps `localhost:` at the start of the display, which won't work if the server isn't listening to TCP connections. A display of the form `localhost:10` isn't equivalent to `:10`, although they have similar effects if both work: the form with a host name goes via a TCP connection, whereas the form without a host name uses a Unix socket, which might be all that's available (and which allows optimizations even if TCP is available, but I doubt that those optimizations do anything when the connection is then relayed through TCP by SSH).

The reason to prefer `echo add … | xauth -` rather than `xauth add …` is that another user snooping on the processes you create could catch the `xauth` command line. Since `echo` is a shell builtin, they won't be able to recover the cookie with the `echo add …` form.

Comment: But both the "normal" xauth way and the rc way of setting the cookie happens directly at login time before I am able to set up some kind of home directory. Therefore I have no chance to put a proper `~/.ssh/rc` in place. - Seems like there is no way to set the cookie without some help of root.

Comment: @michas If you aren't able to put an sshrc file, then the command won't run automatically, but you can still run it manually (possibly by running a client-side script that does this then runs an interactive shell).

Comment: Sure, I can run it manually, but at that time I don't know the value of the cookie. As far as I understood, that value is only passed at startup. If there is no custom rc script in place and no way to tell xauth to write to a custom location, than there is no other way to get the value of the cookie.

Comment: @michas I see the problem but not the solution. There doesn't seem to be a way to get the cookie unless you can perform some configuration on the server side. Can you edit the `authorized_keys` file? If so one solution would be to define `HOME` through an `environment` directive on the public key. Another solution if you have recent enough versions on OpenSSH (≥6.7) on both sides and you trust the server enough to use `ssh -Y` would be to [forward the X11 socket](https://lwn.net/Articles/609321/). If your X server accepts TCP connections you can of course forward just that and copy the cookie.